# In notepad++ can you replace chars in a match group

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given a string (without the quotes) 'this lar-g-e tiger' if I want to replace the hyphens in the middle word can this be done in notepad++

I was hoping I could match the middle group and perform a kind of replacement on it.

So for example, the text:

> ```
> this lar-g-e tig-er
> the f-a-s-t car
> ```

would become:

> ```
> this lar_g_e tig-er
> the f_a_s_t car
> ```

The rule here is that the '-' to '_' replacement should only happen in the middle word.

Comment: Of course,but can you please give more information on what you want to achieve ***exactly***

Comment: updated with an example

Comment: does the text `this lar-g-e tiger--` become `this lar_g_e tiger--` ?

Comment: No, I have updated the question with examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update according to request change:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^\w+\h+|\G)(\w+)-`
- Replace with: `$1$2_`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(       : start group 1
  ^     : beginning of line
  \w+   : 1 or more word character, you may use [a-z]+ if you want letters only
  \h+   : 1 or more horizontal space
 |      : OR
  \G    : start next match from here
)       : end group 1
(       : start group 2
  \w+   : 1 or more word character, you may use [a-z]+ if you want letters only
)       : end group 2
-       : a dash
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
$2      : content of group 2
_       : an underscore
```

**Result for given example:**

```
this lar_g_e tiger
the f_a_s_t car
```

Comment: Very nice but this will also replace underscores from the other words. I will update my example to show they should not be edited.

Comment: @AndyCribbens: What are the rules? Why `lar-g-e` is changed but not `tig-er`? Please, edit your question and add the rules.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the rule at the end

Comment: @AndyCribbens: I had already done the update. Does it work for you?